# Эффект появления и исчезания текста в Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, анимация, label

Как сделать так, чтобы был эффект появления и исчезания текста в виджете `Label`?

Это словно на черном фоне понемногу начинает появляться текст на 2-3 сек. и также исчезает.

**main.py**:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Пример текста", font=("Arial", 16), fg="#000000", bg="#000000")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
_bg="#000000"

label = tk.Label(root, 
    text="Пример текста", 
    font=("Arial", 16), 
    fg="#000000", 
    bg=_bg
)
label.pack()

def animate_label(_bg, n=0):
    _bg = f'#{str(hex(int(_bg[1:], 16) + 1052688))[2:]}' 
    #print(f'{_bg}') 
    if n < 14:
        label.after(100, animate_label, _bg, n+1)
    label['fg'] = _bg
    
root.after(100, animate_label, _bg)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nove_Under889 что не так?